# Doesn't Laplace's equation describe the local property of space?

Tags: electrostatics

$$\nabla^2 \phi = 0$$ is Laplace's equation used "**wherever $\rho = 0$, that is in all parts of space where there is no electric charge.**". However,how can Laplace's equation be used outside a conductor having charge distributed on its surface? In the case of a charged conductor, $\rho \neq 0$. So, how can Laplace's equation be used? After all, it is applied when $\rho= 0$ ? Where am I mistaking? Perhaps, it describes the local property of the space & hence be applied outside the charged conductor as the space outside the conductor is a free space, right?

And another problem I am having is along the surface of the charged conductor. There, $\rho \ne 0$. However, as the surface is equipotential, Laplace equation can be applied, right? If this is so, I would argue again of the applicability of Laplace's equation as on the surface $\rho \ne 0$. Confused:(

Can anyone help me removing my confusion?

Comment: At any point where the charge density is zero, Laplace's equation holds, even if the charge density is non-zero elsewhere.

Comment: @joshphysics: So, it's describing a local property then.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a local property. The general equation for electro statics is $\nabla^2 \phi(\textbf{r}) = - \rho(\textbf{r})/\epsilon_0$. The second derivative of $\phi$ at a point $\textbf{r}_0$ is proportional to $\rho$ at $\textbf{r}_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laplace's equations, as well as all other kinds of fields equations, always describe a local property, whether or not the right hand side is non-zero. In particular, it restricts all the possible fields configurations to the ones obeying
$$
\nabla^2 \phi(x,t)= f(x,t).
$$
It describes the local properties of the field $\phi$ upon the space in the region where the equation holds. In order for the solution to be well defined, boundary conditions must be fulfilled and this has to be eventually checked a posteriori, especially under the assumption that the right hand side is discontinuos at some points (i. e. it becomes zero all of a sudden outside the conductor). But this is a problem of its solutions, not of the equation itself, which holds always anyway.